# os.O_EXLOCK (exclusive lock) doesn't exist in Python on Linux

Tags: python, python-2.6

As you can see below, I'm running Python 2.6 on Linux (RHEL), but it doesn't have os.O_EXLOCK for some reason. Is there some reason why? And is there a way around this?

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr  9 2010, 11:16:46) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.O_EXLOCK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'O_EXLOCK'
>>> os.O_DSYNC
4096
>>>
```

Comment: It seems BSD-specific e.g., iOS has `os.O_EXLOCK`.

Comment: @Kyo, in your operating system, you will note that `man 2 open` doesn't have `O_EXLOCK` listed either. It would seem that only the intersection of the options listed there and in the `os` module can be expected to be available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in [the Python Standard Library documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#open-flag-constants),

> The following constants are options for the flags parameter to the
>   open() function. They can be combined using the bitwise OR operator |.
>   Some of them are not available on all platforms. For descriptions of
>   their availability and use, consult the open(2) manual page on Unix or
>   the MSDN on Windows.

`O_EXLOCK` [originated in the BSD world](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open_002dtime-Flags.html);  it is not normally available on Linux.  You might be able to use the [Python `fcntl` module](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html) instead.